# Glitchy/distorted object when exporting to .obj file format but looks fine while in Blender

Tags: objects, edit-mode, wireframe

** I am new to Blender

I am trying to model and export a Glock 18 for my game. In viewing in Edit mode, Object mode, Shading or basically every mode in Blender, the weapon looks fine and doesn't get distorted until exporting the object to .obj format.
[image: Exported .obj file]

Here's what it looks like in Blender:
[image: Object]

And here's its wireframe:
[image: Object wireframe]

Is there anything wrong with the wireframe or how I exported it that affected the .obj file? Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Did you apply the scale to all the objects it is made from before exporting?

Comment: I kept the original scale. I also tried to import it as an .fbx file and it has the same error, so the problem must be with the wireframe. However, when I imported it into Unity and Unreal, both objects aren't distorted. I'm really confused

Comment: You'll need to upload the blend file ( https://pasteall.org/blend/ ) in that case so that someone can have a look.

Comment: Looks like triangulation problem. Transform all your non coplanar faces to triangles before exporting

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/aeb1a95eb16b4930b4af0fd859e7ea9c // Here's my .blend file, excuse the crappy modelling because I'm new. I also followed @Gorgious instructions and it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Try to recalculate normals in blender. Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sK2pDByXOE A similar face-missing problem, where they recommend to recalculate normals.: https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/s5u5ve/missing_texturemeshes_in_import_from_blender_to/

Answer (score 1):

Try to recalculate normals in blender.First, face orientation:
[image]

2nd, switch to edit mode, select all the vectors, edges and faces, choose normals under mesh:
[image]

3rd, choose recalculate outside.

Here is an example more detailed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sK2pDByXOE

A similar face-missing problem, where they recommend to recalculate normals.:
https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/s5u5ve/missing_texturemeshes_in_import_from_blender_to/